# Reference error: TWEEN is not defined

Tags: javascript, tween.js

I'm trying to use the Tween.js library. However, when my javascript's code runs I receive a reference error in the degub console which states that TWEEN is not defined. My code is the following

```
function armTween(){ 
    var position = {x: -20, y: squareSize*11, z : 10};
    var target = {x: -10, y: -1.75, z: -10};

    var tween = new TWEEN.Tween(position)
            .to(target, 500)
            .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Elastic.InOut).
            onUpdate(function(){
                console.log("onUpdate");
                    lowerArm.position.x = position.x;
                    lowerArm.position.y = position.y;
                    lowerArm.position.z = position.z;
            });

    tween.start();
```

Also, My index.html file contains the import statement for Tween.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>3D Checkers</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="boardContainer" class="boardContainer"></div>

    <script src="js/three/three.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three/Projector.js"></script>
    <script src="js/three/OrbitControls.js"></script>

    <script src="js/Game.js"></script>
    <script src="js/BoardController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

    <script src="js/tween/Tween.js"></script>

</body>
```

I can't figure out how this reference error can be solved. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to import `tween.js` before the script you call it from

Comment: Try moving the Tween include above the js files that use it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `tween.js` before the script you call it from.

You always want to include your libraries and resource scripts before your behaviour scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import Tween.js before your scripts that depend on it?